# Move twitter bootstrap select

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, select, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a bit of trouble moving the bootstrap-select selectpicker plugin.  The docs at http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/ don't seem to indicate that this is ever an issue.  Modifying the select that the custom select is based on does not seem to move the custom select, and using js to alter the css of .select, the css class for the element visible on the screen when using the selectpicker plugin, results in a flash from one position to another.  It's not pretty.

Does anyone with experience using bootstrap-select.js think they could lend a hand?

Things I've tried:

`select {
  display: block;
  margin-left: "insert offset here"
}`

`.select {
  display: block; 
  margin-left: "insert offset here"
}`

`select {
  display: block;
  margin-right: "insert negative offset here"
}`

`.select {
  display: block;
  margin-right: "insert negative offset here"
}`

Css seems to be overwritten when .selectpicker() is called.

`$(document).ready(function() {$('.select').css('margin-left', '50px'););})
  // Nothing happens because selectpicker is still being initialized.`

`setTimeout(function() {$('.select').css('margin-left', '50px');}, 10);
  // Results in a visible flicker and is not guaranteed to work because of race conditions.`

Comment: Can you post some code to show us what you've tried?

Comment: Sure.  My apologies for the rather vague post.